# Outlook365 - How do I print a whole email THREAD to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I see how to print one message at a time.

How do I print a whole thread?

(Outlook on line, aka Office365)

Comment: I don't think Outlook Online provides a way to print the whole message thread at a time.

Comment: @SteveFan So it seems. I find the online app pretty weak. (And I will only ever use the online app, so I am stuck with it.)